# SQL filter using user input if provided

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a SQL query:

```
$q='SELECT i.RID, i.ITEM, i.ITEMNAME, i.Desc,
GROUP_CONCAT(concat(m.META_NAME, ": ", m.META_VALUE)) AS Meta, l.Building, l.PERSON_TYPE 
FROM LAF_Lost_Items AS i INNER JOIN LAF_Lost_Items_Metadata AS m ON i.RID=m.RID AND i.ITEM=m.ITEM 
INNER JOIN LAF_Lost_Inquiries AS l ON l.RID=i.RID 
WHERE (i.ClaimID IS NULL) AND (l.Building=?) AND (dateLost > ?) AND (META_NAME IN (?) OR META_VALUE IN (?)) 
GROUP BY i.RID, i.ITEM;';
$DB->query($q, array($_POST["Building"], $_POST["dateLost"], $_POST["META_NAME"], $_POST["META_VALUE"]));
$r=$DB->fetch_assoc_all();
```

This query works, but uses empty values if the user does not provide anything, which gives the wrong result.

How can I write SQL query that would filter the results using only values provided by the user? When user clicks submit button, an ajax call happens and a new table is drawn.

These two answers [sql filter table data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14424769/sql-filter-table-data) and [SQL Filter Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165581/sql-filter-query) are close to what I need, but I am not sure how to adapt them for my situation.

P.S. Added breaks for better readability

Edit 1: Added screenshot. Building and Meta Names are always present.

[image]

Comment: Would there ever be a case when META_NAME was present but META_VALUE wasn't, or vice versa?  what would be the correct query in that case?

Comment: What about just writing the second piece of the where after you check if is an empty value? Don't you like the idea?

Comment: @Gus I added a picture of how it looks like. It is possible, the query will need to look up Book for the item from items_meta table and it's respective value.

Comment: @Lucarnosky I was thinking about checking for empty values, and if not, then append necessary WHERE conditions to SQL query. Isn't there a better way than that?

Comment: @Biarys I use that technique, is not that bad if you can organize it. I save my condition to an array and the use an implode function appending all of them to mtain query

Comment: In this case where only the WHERE clause is changing, it's probably easiest to just append the where clause.  Since you've got a static portion of the where clause, it's really simple to just iterate each POST element and append "AND <additional clause element>" to the existing statement for each element that is both present and valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Lucarnosky and @Gus, I ended up checking if $_POST variables are not empty and then adding them to a string. This is how code currently looks like:

```
$s = "";
foreach ($_POST as $i => $values) {
    if (!is_array($values)) {
        if (!empty($values)){
            echo $i . ": " . $values . "\n";
            $s .= " AND " . $i . "=" . $values . " ";
        }
    }
    else {
        foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
            if (!empty($value)) {
                echo $i . ": " . $key . ": " . $value . "\n";
                $s .= " AND " . $key . "=" . $value . " ";
            }
        }
    }
}

$q='SELECT i.RID, i.ITEM, i.ITEMNAME, i.Desc, 
GROUP_CONCAT(concat(m.META_NAME, ": ", m.META_VALUE)) AS Meta, l.Building, l.PERSON_TYPE 
FROM LAF_Lost_Items AS i INNER JOIN LAF_Lost_Items_Metadata AS m ON i.RID=m.RID AND i.ITEM=m.ITEM 
INNER JOIN LAF_Lost_Inquiries AS l ON l.RID=i.RID 
WHERE ' . $s . ' GROUP BY i.RID, i.ITEM;';
```

If you have a better answer, please let me know.